# UI5 - navigation event get fired but view does not change

Tags: sapui5

I want to navigate through my UI5 app. The navigation event get fired and the event get catched but my view does not change. After a refresh the view changed correctly because the url hash changed correctly... Why does the view does not change although the route works.

```
onRoutePatternMatched: function(event) {
            var partnerId = event.getParameters().arguments.partnerId;
            console.log("Two: " + partnerId);
                this.getView().bindElement({
                    path: "/partners('" + partnerId + "')"
                });
        }
```

Comment: My guess is that you might be utilizing a SplitApp control and clicking on an item which is in the Master View. Using routing you are expecting to navigate to Detail. But most likely the Detail View is already rendered and you simple want to change the BindingContext. In short, to navigate to some new view, utilize sap.m.Router.navTo(routeName) [link](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.core.sample.RoutingFullscreen/preview) [link](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#demoapps.html). Download the Shopping Cart app from the second link for an example.

Comment: @Sid No I don't use a SplitApp. Just a single App with pages.

Comment: I see. In that case: 1. Check if each views/page is added to the App control and 2. Check if you have called navTo() on the Router control. Finally if you have called the navTo() on the Router - can you please paste the code here so that we can see if there is any issue with it?